# matplotlib - Legend with multiple axes with errorbar object

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having trouble to get legends on a plot with two axes sets and an errorbar. The code goes as follows:

```
rect = 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8
fig = p.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_axes(rect)
errorplot = ax1.errorbar(x, y, yerr = yerr, fmt = "o", label = r"errorbar")
plot1 = ax1.plot(x1, y1, "^", color = "#00FF7F", label = r"plot")
ax1.yaxis.tick_left()
ax1.xaxis.tick_bottom()
ax2 = fig.add_axes(rect, frameon=False)
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
ax2.xaxis.tick_top()
ax2.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
plot2 = ax2.plot(z, al, color = "#CD8500", linewidth =2, label= r"plot2")
k = list(errorplot[:1])
plots = k + plot1 + plot2
labels = [l.get_label() for l in k]
ax1.legend(plots, labels, loc = 2 )
ax1.legend(loc = 2)
p.savefig("test.pdf")
```

This works if plot1 is not an errorbar plot. Any recommendations to get a legend with all plots in one box?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344063/single-legend-for-multiple-axes) should work:

```
h1, l1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax1.legend(h1+h2, l1+l2, loc=2)
```