# Use different font properties for label in matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

I would like to use 2 different font size in the same legend in a matplotlib graph.

For exemple, I would like to use a 15 points bold font for some labels and 10 points normal font for the others labels in the same legend box.

My plot legend already regroup legend from 2 axes ([Single legend for multiple axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344063/single-legend-for-multiple-axes)) and have a variable number of data plotted.

I already use blank data strategy to add annotation to the legend plot ([Is it possible to add a string as a legend item in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826711/is-it-possible-to-add-a-string-as-a-legend-item-in-matplotlib)). But I would like to make it with a bigger sized, bolt fount if it's possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use the following pattern on the [`Text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text) objects contained in the legend() :

```
leg = plt.legend()

for i, text in enumerate(leg.get_texts()):

    # pretend the element to be changed is in index position 3
    if i == 3: 
        text.set_weight("bold")
        text.set_size("x-large")

        # or equivalently with one call to setp()
        plt.setp(text, weight="bold", size="x-large")
```

EDIT:
Looks like changing things in one text object inside a legend actually applies to all objects. One workaround that works is to use [mathtext](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#custom-fonts) like so `text.set_text(r'$\mathbf{label}$')`. In the loop, we'd need to retrieve the label and deal with mathtext "condensing" the spaces. Here's an example:

```
line1, = plt.plot([3,2,1], marker='o', label='Line 1 label is long and has spaces')
line2, = plt.plot([1,2,3], marker='o', label='Line 2')
leg = plt.legend()

for i, text in enumerate(leg.get_texts()):

    # the element to be changed is in index position 0
    if i == 0: 
        t = text.get_text()
        new_label = "".join([i + r"\/" for i in t.split()])
        text.set_text(r'$\mathbf{}$'.format("{" + new_label + "}"))
```

I don't know if using mathtext or latex is acceptable to you, but it appears to allow unique formatting of a single legend text label.

Comment: It didn't work for me. It change the properties of all legend text at the same time. Look like it can't handle different legend text font properties in the same legend.

I tried too:
for i, text in enumerate(leg.get_texts()):
    # pretend the element to be changed is in index position 3
    print i
    if i == 0:
        text.set_weight("bold")
        text.set_size("x-large")
    else:
       text.set_weight("medium")
       text.set_size("x-small")

But legend text will be all "medium" "x-small" of whatever the last item condition dictate.

Comment: Hm, you're right. It doesn't look like the `text` instances inside a `legend` are really first-class citizens. However, I was able to adjust the fontweight using [mathtext](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html#custom-fonts), see edited answer.

Comment: i meant "are **not** really first-class citizens"