# How to plot two pandas time series on same plot with legends and secondary y-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot two time series on the same plot with same x-axis and secondary y-axis. I have somehow achieved this, but two legends are overlapping and is unable to give label to x-axis and secondary y-axis.I tried putting two legend at upper-left and upper-right, but it is still not working.

Code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))

# Number of request every 10 minutes
log_10minutely_count_Series = log_df['IP'].resample('10min').count()
log_10minutely_count_Series.name="Count"
log_10minutely_count_Series.plot(color='blue', grid=True)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel('Number of request ever 10 minute')

# Sum of response size over each 10 minute
log_10minutely_sum_Series = log_df['Bytes'].resample('10min').sum()
log_10minutely_sum_Series.name = 'Sum'
log_10minutely_sum_Series.plot(color='red',grid=True, secondary_y=True)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The following solutions work for me. The first places both lines in one legend, the second splits lines into two legends, similar to what you are trying above.

Here is my dataframe

```
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=ts.index, columns=list('ABCD'))
```

One legend solution, credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344063/single-legend-for-multiple-axes) StackOverflow post

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.xlabel('Number of requests every 10 minutes')

ax1 = df.A.plot(color='blue', grid=True, label='Count')
ax2 = df.B.plot(color='red', grid=True, secondary_y=True, label='Sum')

h1, l1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()


plt.legend(h1+h2, l1+l2, loc=2)
plt.show()
```

[image: One legend matplotlib plot]

Split legend solution

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.xlabel('Number of requests every 10 minutes')

ax1 = df.A.plot(color='blue', grid=True, label='Count')
ax2 = df.B.plot(color='red', grid=True, secondary_y=True, label='Sum')

ax1.legend(loc=1)
ax2.legend(loc=2)

plt.show()
```

[image: Split legend matplotlib plot]

Comment: For the split-legend plot, it's better to interchange the legends' `loc`s, because loc=1 is for top right, and the right-y-axis is the secondary y-axis, while loc=2 is for top left (closer to the primary y-axis). See the docs for legend: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Answer (score 10):

It can be as simple as:

```
df.loc[:,['A','B']].plot(secondary_y=['B'], mark_right=False, figsize = (20,5), grid=True)
```

mark_right=False means that 'B' label is on the left axis.